# Set up live notifications

Tags: push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, alert

I'm a football fan and I'm following a strict betting strategy when a live game becomes 2-2, however I'm tired to constantly follow all live games, so I need a solution.

I'm not a technical guru, and that is why I need some help.

What I do is:

- I follow this live page https://www.spreadex.com/sports/en-GB/spread-betting/live-in-play OR https://bg.futbol24.com/Live/
- I'm monitoring and I need any live game to become 2-2

What I need is:

- somehow to setup some kind of notification when a live game become 2-2

Can you think of any tool I can use in order to achieve that? Or any script I can write?

Thank you in advance!

I tried a few paid products , but none of them did the trick.

I do expect to write something on my own, and some guidance how to do it